# Splitting lines with polygons that do not intersect using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, splitting

Is it possible to split polylines based on the boundary of the nearest polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?

I am trying to split a multi-part sidewalk layer based on adjacent parcel boundaries and assign each resulting split sidewalk the address of that parcel.  The problem is that most of the sidewalk does not fall within a parcel boundary.

[image]

Comment: It's probably doable, but could you show a screenshot of your parcel / sidewalk layers so that I can try to replicate it?

Comment: why yes, that is absolutely possible.

Comment: okay, to avoid confusion; as a new user please have a look at the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what makes a question fit the focussed Q&A concept of this board. apart from details about your data it's essential to name the software you intend to use. be specific ,)

Comment: Where is your sidewalk layer coming from? Are the actual sidewalks intermittent like that?

Comment: The gaps in the sidewalk layer are either driveways or areas where  there are actual gaps in the sidewalk for one reason or another.

Comment: id be surprised if this could be done in arcgis desktop without the use of python, postgis or another programming language

Comment: does this have to be in arcgis environment? could you take an answer in SQL?

Comment: Densify and split at vertices. Run near on parcels and dissolve.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not worried about accuracy why not try this approach?

- Convert the sidewalk into points (feature to points tool)
- Run the generate near table tool
- Now you have grouped points by the nearby polygon ID, you reconstruct your lines but group by polyline ID (Points To Line tool).

A limitation is that a single walkway line composed of 2 vertices would fail to reconstruct but then I guess you could simply half the line in that case? Also it would introduce a gap between changing polygons.

What ever approach you use I agree with @ziggy that it will involve some sort of scripting approach.

Comment: `2 vertices would fail to reconstruct` why would that be?

Comment: I'm looking at the second from the bottom left sidewalk in the image above. vertex 1 would be one polygon, vertex 2 would be second polygon. So the near tool would group them into separate polygon ID's giving you only 1 point to create a polyline which as you know ain't gonna work. I'm sure there is a more nifty approach out there, but for quick and dirty this may be all that is required?

Comment: oh yeah I see what you mean